# Is there a way to remove custom ringtones from an iPhone without using a Mac or PC?

Tags: iphone, garageband, ringtones

[This question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/298688/how-to-delete-remove-custom-ringtones-tones-from-iphone-in-itunes-12-7) has good answers on how to remove ringtones that one may have installed using iTunes on a Mac or PC.

However, it appears to be possible for iPhone users who do not have a Mac or PC to create and install custom ringtones using the iOS Garageband app (see [here](https://www.howtoisolve.com/create-ringtone-directly-iphone-7-plus-using-garageband/) and [here](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2017/05/25/how-to-create-ringtone-text-tone-garageband/)).  Is it possible to remove those user-created custom ringtones from an iPhone (without having to find a Mac or PC with iTunes)?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Press **Select**.
2. Choose any of your recordings, it doesn’t matter.
3. Press the button of the box with an arrow pointing up in the bottom left corner.
4. Press the **Ringtone** button.
5. Press **Your Ringtones**.
6. Slide left the ringtone(s) you want to delete, and there should be a Delete button.

Comment: In which iOS app or page to do step 1?