# Deleting Custom ringtones from iPhone / iTunes 12.7

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization, ringtones

I've followed the instructions from [How to delete/remove custom ringtones (tones) from iPhone in iTunes 12.7?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/298688/how-to-delete-remove-custom-ringtones-tones-from-iphone-in-itunes-12-7/298711), but the ringtones are still on the iPhone after I sync, even though in iTunes the tones are no longer there. How can I remove the tones from my phone?

Answer (score 2):

You can delete custom ringtones right on your iPhone using GarageBand.

1. Launch GarageBand on your iPhone
2. If you’ve never created a song on GarageBand, then you need to create one. It doesn’t matter what you create, you just need to have a song on the “Recents” screen.
3. Navigate to the “Recents” screen and long-tap on one of the songs.
4. Some floating options will appear
5. Select “Share” and then select “Ringtone”.
6. If a message appears about ringtones being 30 sec long etc’, just press “Continue”.
7. You should now be on the export screen. Press on “My Ringtones”.
8. A list of your custom ringtones will appear.
9. Press on “Edit”.
10. Delete the ringtones you don’t need.
11. That’s it. You can now cancel back to the main screen